# Given a continuous function $f$, is there any interval on which $f$ is not either weakly convex or weakly concave?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a continuous function $f$, is there any interval on which $f$ is not either weakly convex or weakly concave?

If not, is there some class of functions that are only either weakly convex or weakly concave?

Comment: Consider any function $f$ which is twice differentiable but whose second derivative takes both positive and negative values of any interval.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio such a function does not exist if its second derivative is to be continuous at any point.

Comment: Not at all. The derivative of a differentiable function is not necessarily continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You may just consider a function of the form
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(n^3 x)}{n^2}. $$
This is a continuous function since it is given by a totally convergent series of continuous functions, but it is not weakly convex or weakly concave over any interval. Its graph has a fractal structure:

[image]